# How can I find and remove some image element which has a broken link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, broken-image

I have hosted my site on Wordpress. and recently I have been facing the problem of an image link broken in my site. I don't know when it's happened. The problem arises in the only post section.

[image]

Comment: Please add some code to your post so users can give you a hand with your programming issues.

Comment: Put the image back in the location or remove it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, but if you don't know where to start, you can try this with javascript:

```js
function findToDeleteBrokenImages() {
  var images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img"));
  
  for (var image of images) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function () {
      image.parentElement.removeChild(image);
    };
    
    img.src = image.src;
  }
};

findToDeleteBrokenImages();
```

```html
<img src="foo" />
```

But notice that, there are serveral ways to display an image, too. So, if your image is shown as a background of some `div` element or `canvas`, you can use the same logic of the code above, but the way to remove/delete that element is different.